# Powershell Set deny SCM access restriction on App Service

Tags: powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I'm trying to set via powershell deny option for Source Control Manager in Azure:

[image]

[image]

i'm executing this code snippet

```
   $propertiesObject = @{
    http20Enabled = $true;
    ScmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain = $true;
    scmIpSecurityRestrictions = @{"Action" = "Deny"};
}

Set-AzResource -PropertyObject $propertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $AppServiceRG -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "$AppServiceName/web" -ApiVersion 2022-03-01 -Force
```

but it is not working i think becouse that option is an object:

[image]

[image]

How i can set Deny? Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

In azure app service, you can set the unmatched rule action - "Deny" by executing below commands:

**Azure CLI command:**

```
    az resource update --resource-group ResourceGroup --name AppName --resource-type "Microsoft.Web/sites" \
  --set properties.siteConfig.scmIpSecurityRestrictionsDefaultAction=Deny
```

**Powershell command:**

```
$Resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroup -ResourceName AppName
$Resource.Properties.siteConfig.scmIpSecurityRestrictionsDefaultAction = "Deny"
$Resource | Set-AzResource -Force
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

The above command executed successfully and reflected in portal.

[image]

**For more reference:**

[Azure App Service access restrictions - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions?tabs=powershell#change-unmatched-rule-action-for-advanced-tool-site)